# Integration of Facebook Group Wall in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is it possible to integrate a wall of a specific Facebook group into an iPhone application. Is it possible to do using Facebook connect? or any other libraries?

1. The task is to display the wall of a group. Can we bypass sign up and display the activity on the wall on the tab?
2. Would it be possible for a registered FB user to make posts from our iPhone app?

Thank you,

Slava

Comment: Refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343156/how-to-display-facebook-fan-wall-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

You need an `access_token` and query the `GROUP_ID/feed` connection.

For more information see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/