# How to display Facebook Fan Wall in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to display Facebook Fan Wall like the way in the image below. Can you please let me know how it can be done?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi mate, I am also looking for similar functionality! Did you find a way to do this? Is there any GitHub library available to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, we ended up just showing Facebook's fanpage in UIWebview.

Comment: In that case how do you combine all user's comments? User has to comment on your Facebook's fanpage? Can't they comment from iPhone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull in the list of wall feeds from https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/statuses?access_token=... (a preview can be seen with the graph api explorer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=cocacola/statuses)).  Then you would just parse the returned JSON and put them into UITableView cells.

Answer (score -1):

You need to post to your friends feed, Easy way would be to adapt your code to use the appropriate graph method with the persons you wish to post to facebook ID (i've assumed here you have stored this from an earlier call the graph api in person.facebookID)

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed/",person.facebookID] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

To get a list of the users friends use the graph path me/friends

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Which will return a JSON list of the users friends names and their Facebook ids, to the appropriate delegate method from FBRequest, its probably worth wrapping this set of results into a set of person objects or storing the returned `NSDictionary` so that you can retrieve individual friends, its upto you how you process the list of returned friends (you probably want to use a `UITableView` to display the user friends or filter based on some other input from the user)

Using this method will mean you do not have to use the Facebook dialogs in the iOS sdk, which does mean there is an upper limit to how many messages the user can post in a day using your app

If you wish to use a dialog you will need to include the `target_id` in your params dictionary and set this to the persons Facebook ID you wish to post to