# Opinion/Comment system with facebook iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-comments

I'm developing a tourist guide, on iOS 6.1. I have a section with some hotels or inns.

I have a Facebook login system. I want that the users can post them opinions in a box, about a specific hotel.

So, what is the best option?

1. Can I post It with Facebook account, and show all comments about that hotel? Is it possible? How? (It would be nice)
2. I have to save the user Facebook name in a field on the DB, then save all comments on the DB to load them?

**EDIT:**

I did a design to exemplify the example:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
I'll give another bounty, because I think there are best solutions and I would like to get all the steps to do this system.

Comment: Where do you want to post it? To the hotel's fan page? the the use's wall?

Comment: It's that I want to know... I just want a comment system for each hotel, with the facebook account. I have several hotels on my app, it's not for only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plugin based solutions :**

Looks like facebook released a comment plugin for iOS :

[https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-media/bringing-facebook-comments-to-mobile/306485919386904](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343156/how-to-display-facebook-fan-wall-in-iphone-app)

This guy created a solution based on inlined UIWebView and a tiny hack :

http://suhinini.me/2011/05/24/embedding-facebook-social-comments-plugin-to-an-ios-application/

---

**Fan page based solution :**

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343156/how-to-display-facebook-fan-wall-in-iphone-app), you could get the list of wall feeds from the Hotel's fan page (if it has one) from https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/statuses?access_token=... Parse the returned JSON to display them.

**If the hotel doesn't have a fan page :**

According to the question, your Facebook login works.

Save the comment to the DB with the Hotel_ID and the user Facebook_ID, so you can diplay that comment in your app anyway.

Prompt a simple Facebook "share" window so if he wants, he can post it on his wall.

Hope this helps! :D